Complex representation of Lie group is self-conjugate if and only if character is real valued?
A representation $ \rho: G \to \mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C}) $ is called self-conjugate if $ \rho \cong \overline{\rho} $ where $ \overline{\rho} $ is the conjugate representation given by $  g \mapsto \overline{\rho(g)} $.
Let $ G $ be a Lie group. Let $ \rho: G \to \mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C}) $ be a representation of $ G $ with character $ \chi_\rho $. Is it true that $ \rho $ is self-conjugate if and only if $ \chi_\rho $ is real valued?
For $ G $ a finite group this is true since a complex representation of a finite group is determined up to isomorphism by its character.
Another example that is consistent with this is that for $ \mathrm{SU}(2) $ every representation is self-conjugate and every character is real.
Update: as pointed out in the comments the method for finite groups extends pretty directly to compact groups. And I assume from compact groups it extends pretty readily to complex representations of reductive algebraic groups. So then the question would be to see what happens for easy examples of non-reductive groups, like 2-step nilpotent groups.

Representations of compact groups are also determined up to isomorphism by the character, since the orthogonality relations are also true in this case, with basically the same proof.

@QiaochuYuan I see, so I guess it is true for any reductive algebraic group as well? And then I guess there are easy examples of even 2-step nilpotent groups which have non-isomorphic representations with the same character?

If $G$ is any group (Lie, algebraic, etc) whose f.d. representation theory is not semisimple, then any non-semisimple representation and its semisimplification will have the same character.

@QiaochuYuan Oh ok cool. Is there any easy way to apply this to get an answer to the title question? Like this group $ \begin{bmatrix} e^{i \theta} & z \ 0 & e^{-i \theta} \end{bmatrix} $ has real character but maybe it is not self-conjugate?
